# Contando valores 'nan' e 'null' em um dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Imagine que temos um arquivo CSV chamado dados.csv:

```
col1    col2    col3   col4
1        2        3        4
5       6         7        8
9      10        11       12
13     14        15    
33    44

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

po = pd.read_csv('/dados.csv')
```

Meu objetivo é entender melhor como identificar dados Nan/null em um dataset.

Perguntas:

1.Como contar quantos dados 'nan' existem no dataset acima?

2.Como contar quantos dados null existem no dataset acima?

3.Como contar quantos dados NÃO 'nan' existem no dataset acima?

4.Como contar quantos dados NÃO 'null' existem no dataset acima?

E as mesmas questões acima mas por coluna?

Eu tentei, por exemplo,:

```
po[po['col4'].isna()].count()
```

pensando em contas quantos 'nan' existem na coluna 4, mas a resposta foi:

```
col1    2
col2    2
col3    1
col4    0
dtype: int64
```

O que está errado? Como responder as perguntas acima?

Comment: @NoobSaibot : Não concordo. Fiz 4 questões referentes ao dataset acima (csv) na qual cada resposta seria uma linha de código!

Comment: @NoobSaibot: a minha grande dúvida é Como contar quantos dados null/nan existem? E quantos não são "nan/null" para aplicar isso em um dataset maior...

Comment: @NoobSaibot: tentei aplicar aqui mas não entendi a saída!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que está errado?

A função [`count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html#pandas-dataframe-count) faz contagem de dados não-nulos (para cada coluna ou linha), o uso correto dela é:

- Contagem de dados não-nulos de todas as colunas

  ```
  print(po.count())
  ```

  a saída será:

  ```
  col1    5
  col2    5
  col3    4
  col4    3
  dtype: int64
  ```
- Contagem de dados não-nulos de uma coluna específica

  ```
  print(po.col4.count())
  ```

  a saída será:

  ```
  3
  ```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AchingMisguidedAutomaticparallelization)

Para fazer a contagem de dados ausentes, você pode utilizar a função [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas.DataFrame.isna) ou a função [`isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html#pandas.DataFrame.isnull)

- Contagem de dados ausentes de todas as colunas

  ```
  # isna
  print(po.isna().sum())

  # isnull
  print(po.isnull().sum())
  ```

  a saída de ambos será:

  ```
  col1    0
  col2    0
  col3    1
  col4    2
  dtype: int64
  ```
- Contagem de dados ausentes de uma coluna específica

  ```
  # isna
  print(po.col4.isna().sum())

  # isnull
  print(po.col4.isnull().sum())
  ```

  a saída de ambos será:

  ```
  2
  ```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BubblyWobblyListener)

#### Referências:

- [pandas.DataFrame.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html#pandas-dataframe-count)
- [pandas.DataFrame.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas.DataFrame.isna)
- [pandas.DataFrame.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html#pandas.DataFrame.isnull)

Answer (score 0):

1 e 2: quantos dados 'nan' existem no dataset acima -> po.isna().sum().sum()

Comment: Use o link de edição em sua pergunta para adicionar outras informações. O botão Publicar resposta deve ser usado apenas para concluir respostas à pergunta. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/174931)

Comment: @perozzo: mas isso é uma resposta sim!